# How to run a python exe via Azure Pipeline

Tags: python, azure-pipelines

I created a python script that I then converted to an executable file, the requirement is to run this executable via an Azure pipeline as part of and at the end of a data loading/tabular model refreshing process that starts with SSIS package run (data load into tables), SSAS tabular model processing and then collecting processing statistics - the last part is what this python script is responsible for.

So how do I trigger the python script via the Azure Pipeline, I found an article about this from Microsoft but it is very sparse on details.

I have also read articles about using Azure containers but not much examples that I could follow successfully.

Comment: You can try to run executable file in a cmd task , for example: `start $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\XXX.exe`

Comment: Not get your latest information, is the workaround helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.